# create user with extended claim with scim2 in wso2

Tags: wso2, createuser, scim2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to create a user with scim2 API in wso2 with my own extended claim
my API request
`{
    "schemas": ["urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"],
    "name": {
        "familyName": "jackson",
        "givenName": "kim"
    },
    "userName": "test3",
    "password": "abc123",
    "demoRole":"student",
    "emails": [
        {
            "primary": true,
            "value": "kim.jackson@gmail.com",
            "type": "home"
        },
        {
            "value": "kim_j@wso2.com",
            "type": "work"
        }
    ],
    "roles":[
        {
            "value": "PRIMARY/manager"
        }
    ]
}`

and the configuration in scim2-schema-extension.config.xml is

`{
    "attributeURI":"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User:demoRole",
    "attributeName":"demoRole",
    "dataType":"string",
    "multiValued":"false",
    "description":"The displayName of the User's manager.",
    "required":"false",
    "caseExact":"false",
    "mutability":"readwrite",
    "returned":"default",
    "uniqueness":"none",
    "subAttributes":"null",
    "canonicalValues":[],
    "referenceTypes":["external"]
},`

my claim configuration is

Claim URI  ->           urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User:demoRole

Mapped Local Claim ->   http://wso2.org/claims/demoRole

Comment: not clear about the issue that you are facing?

Comment: i am not able to add demoRole value to user with this api

Comment: @ankalal, what is the WSO2 IS version you are trying with?

Answer (score 0):

Attribute URI for your schema extension should be,

> urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:demoRole

So, External claim URI for urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User will be,

> urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:demoRole

SCIM2 create user request should contain the demoRole as,

> "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User":{"demoRole":"student"}

For more details on the schema extension representation, refer the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643#section-8.3)